# Package to detect most common typing mistakes

Tags: package, hooks

I'm a decent touch-typist, capping out around 90 WPM, but I know I'd be better if I eliminated some of the more persistent typos that crop up semi-consistently.

It occurred to me this morning that since I do almost all my writing and programming in Emacs, it should be able to give me a good idea of what my most common typos are and what context they occur in, based on what characters and words I delete then replace immediately.

From there, I should be able to do some typing drills to eliminate those errors in my typing technique.

I did a few searches on the net looking for such a thing but was not able to find it.

Does anyone know of such a thing existing already?

If not, what would be a good starting point for building it?

I'd think some combination of `post-self-insert-hook`, advising the deletion functions, and perhaps digging around in undo history should make something like this possible, but I'd be delighted to discover someone already did the hard work and I'm just failing to find it.

Comment: I'm thinking about [Abbrev](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/autocorrection_abbrev_defs) or maybe [Ispell+abbrev](https://endlessparentheses.com/ispell-and-abbrev-the-perfect-auto-correct.html).

Comment: I actually want to fix my typing technique, not auto-correct the errors - I've updated the question to clarify that. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/jpablobr/emacs-monkeytype isn't quite what I'm looking for but is the closest thing I've found so far.